# Have NSSpeechRecognizer recognize any command

Tags: cocoa, command

Is there any way I can have NSSpeechRecognizer recognize any command I throw at it.  I know I could just have a massive array, but that's too much work and it'll take up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: No.

NSSpeechRecognizer isn't designed to work this way. It's designed only to listen for a specific list of commands.

"Any command" is a massive list even if each is one word; imagine various combinations of different words that could be a "command". Impractical and unlikely to work.

Comment: well I wanted to make a speech to text application, so it doesn't matter if commands interfere

Comment: Same answer: It's not designed to do this. To match against, say, a list of every word in the English language, would be extremely slow and very inaccurate. NSSpeechRecognizer is *not* the solution to your problem.

Comment: darn. Do you know of anything that can be the solution

Comment: There are open-source speech recognition libraries out there. They all trade some accuracy for being able to recognize any voice or vice-versa (ie, require "training" to a voice for better accuracy). Google "open source speech recognition".